# Why is the "::" operator used in std::cout rather than the "." operator?

Tags: c++, std

A pretty basic question, but I've been stumped on this for a while.

Why exactly do we write

```
int main(){
   std::cout << "HelloWorld!";
}
```

Instead of

```
int main(){
   std.cout("HelloWorld!");
}
```

I understand that the :: operator is used to edit functions in classes, but why is it used in this context to call a function in the std class rather than the . operator?

Comment: `std` is not class. It's namespace.

Comment: `.` is only used when you have a *value* on the left hand side. It means to select a member from that value's class.  `.` and `::` are "allophones" of the C++ language - there's no situation where they're both correct and would have different meaning.  But it helps readability because if you see `.` then you know you're working with an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` operator is the scope resolution operator.  The prefix can be either a namespace or a class.

The `.` operator is used to select a member of an object.  The prefix is an expression of structure, union, or class type (and is most commonly the name of an object of that type).

`std` is a namespace, not a class.  Even if it were a class, `std::cout` would still be correct if `cout` were a static member of that class.  `std.cout` would be correct only if `std` were an *object* of a type that has a member named `cout`.

C++ *could* have been defined to use `.` for all these cases, but the use of `::` as the scope resolution operator and `.` as the member selection operator can make code easier to read because it's more explicit. (There are other languages that use `.` for both.)

Answer (score 2):

Because `std` is not an object but a namespace and the [scope resolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#C.2B.2B) `::` is used for specifying the context or scope to use to resolve an identifier, which in C++ can be a class or a namespace. The `.` operator is a member access operator and is used for accessing members of objects rather than names in the scope of a class or namespace.

So `std::cout` means 'the name `cout` in the namespace `std`' whereas for example `std::ios_base::binary` is a constant defined in the scope of the class `ios_base` in the namespace `std` and `foo.x` is a member variable named `x` of an object named `foo`.

Comment: So then is `::` used to access members in namespaces in the same way `.` is used to access members in classes?

Comment: This is not correct. `::` is used for both classes and namespaces.

Comment: @M.M A class can be a 'namespace' in the context of the scope resolution operator. For example, a nested class definition lives in the namespace of its enclosing class.

Comment: No, a class can't be a namespace.  A class does introduce a scope, which is what you mean.

Comment: @M.M I was using ['namespace'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) in the general sense but I admit that is confusing in the context of C++ where it has a more specific meaning. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Your answer starts with "Because `std` is not a class but a namespace" -- but even if `std` were a class, `std::cout` could still be correct.

Comment: @KeithThompson you're right, your answer was better. I've edited mine a bit.